# Relation between entity class and various other entity classes

Tags: symfony, doctrine

**Problem:**

In my Symfony 4.4 app there is a `Notification` entity class (managed via Doctrine ORM 2.7). In real life every `Notification` object can be related to one "subject". This "subject" may be a `Task`, a `Project`, a `Document`, an `Invoice`, a `Contract`, etc. all of which are entity classes themself.

Ideally it would be possible to have a `Notification::getSubject` and `Notification::setSubject` method if that makes sense. And if possible a `NotificationRepository::findBy('subject' => $subject)` would also work – if that makes sense.

**Question:**

What is a clean/good way to design the realation between the `Notification` entity class and all those different "subject" entity classes using Symfony and Doctrine ORM? Is there an OOP Design Pattern that should be used?

Comment: You can add a foreign key to Notification that referers subject; if a notification only can have one subject, would be a onetoone, if can have many subjects, oneToMany, but I think you want OneToOne.

Comment: I'm not aware of any super clean way to do this.  Doctrine does support class inheritance so you could have all your subject classes inherit from a Subject parent.  But from an OOP view point, using inheritance is probably not a good idea.  The answer below explains this in more detail.  But requiring classes such as Document to be aware that they might be a subject of a notification is not very clean.  And it all falls apart if you need yet another relation such as a Log entity.

Answer (score 1):

Since your question is rather vague, I think you should begin defining the entity.
A goood way to start is to make an an [Entity Relationship Diagram](https://www.smartdraw.com/entity-relationship-diagram/).
This is a good thing to begin by thinking about how Entity will interract between them.
A Diagram is verry helpfull when it is to develop a new feature.

Then, when you have a clear idea about what you wanna do, all you have to do is code it.

For the thing you ask, I try to make such a Diagram, but it may be incomplete, because I don't know your project as you are :

[image]

Of course I haven't represent every entity that you describe, but you got the idea.
The good thing with this inheritance is that you'll be able to call `Notification::getSubject` and then you know which kind of subject it is

You'll create entity `Subject`, and then you extends `Task`, a `Project`, a `Document`, an `Invoice`, a `Contract`, etc.

To create inheritance in doctrine :

```
#src\Entity\Subject
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="subject")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\SubjectRepository")
 * @ORM\InheritanceType(value="JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="subject_type", )
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap(value={SUB_TYPE_DOCUMENT=Document::class, SUB_TYPE_PROJECT=Project::class, SUB_TYPE_TASK=Task::class})
 */
abstract class Subject{
    const SUB_TYPE_DOCUMENT = 'DOCUMENT';
    const SUB_TYPE_PROJECT = 'PROJECT';
    const SUB_TYPE_TASK = 'TASK';
...
}
```

```
#src\Entity\Document
class Document extends Subject{
...
}
```

```
#src\Entity\Project 
class Project extends Subject{
...
}
```

```
#src\Entity\Task
class Task extends Subject{
...
}
```

Read more at : https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/inheritance-mapping.html

That's a very classic way to proceed. Now you asking if there is a `Pattern` To be used.
The one that come in mind could be the [Decorator](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/decorator). I recommend you to read about it.

If none of this help you, please edit your question and add more details about what you need...

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. You got my domain model 99% right. :) What do you think about the limitations/drawbacks mentioned by @Cerad in one of the comments to my question?

Comment: Yes that's right, inheritance have a lot of limitations, that's why I advise you to not use it and prefer the Decorator pattern.  It'll even allow you to log thing if you need to. I think that Decorator is a good pattern because maybe one day you'll want to add ``Task`` and ``Project`` both together in one notification. No problem ! You just can "wrap" any of your subject in one notification ! As they all have their own logic !

Comment: But once more, I don't get all of the specifications about your project, and I really advise you to give more details or to read more about ``Decorator`` and not to see it as the solution to all your problems

Comment: I think that if your ``Notification`` will never ever contains more than one ``Subject``, maybe ``Decorator`` is overkill... I think the Factoy pattern seams well too. https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/factory-method. I'm trying to give you lead, but don't take my word for it ;) I don't pretend to be an expert !